# Authenticate user in controller and then redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I have the following code under `projects_controller.rb`

```
class Admin::ProjectsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :require_login

def require_login
  while (adminLogin != 'username')
    redirect_to admin_login_path and return
  end
end
```

And this under `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

# Return the admin user
 def adminLogin
   @email = params[:email]
   @password = params[:password]
   return @email
 end
end
```

I am trying to get the email in that form and pass it to the projects controller so when the email is defined, the admin can log in. When I press the submit button on the form I can see the right email being sent to the projects controller by using `<%= debug @email %>` in the form, but the page redirects to login again. How can I then go to /projects?

[UPDATE]:

`application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery

# Return the admin user

def redirect_unless_admin
@email = params[:email]
password = params[:password]
if (@email == 'username')
  redirect_to admin_projects_path
else
   redirect_to admin_login_path
end
```

end
end

and I require this method in my `projects_controller.rb`. This is just breaking it, redirecting too many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get by with this in application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def redirect_unless_admin
    email = params[:email]
    password = params[:password]
    if params[:email].present? && email == 'username'
      redirect_to admin_projects_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

and this in admin/projects_controller:

```
class Admin::ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :redirect_unless_admin
end
```

That way the `redirect_unless_admin` method is available to any controller that inherits application_controller. You can customize the logic any way you need to figure out which redirect to use, but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: By using your exact code I am getting a `The website rerouted too many times` so I am not quite sure if that's the right thing. If I changed your method to this   `@email = 'username'
    redirect_to( @email == 'username' ? admin_projects_path : admin_login_path )`  It is getting the right email and routing to `/admin/projects` but then it's crashing with again too many times rerouting error

Comment: Cool, give it a shot now. Might have tried to get too fancy with it. When all else fails, just go with a good old if/else :)

Comment: Please see my comment above with the updated code ^^^

Comment: You're missing an end on your if/else statement

Comment: It's there. Just didn't format properly here. The variable is going right in the if statement, so is just the redirect_to which I guess is not redirecting me there. As I have a before each statement, should I tell projects_controller that `email` now has a value ?

Comment: See the edit to the answer. Basically just checks to make sure email params are present

Comment: Nope. It is working perfect though if I make it only on `before_filter :adminLogin, only: :show` show action. So it's behaving weird just if I have :index in the filter, or I can say the filter on the :index action

Comment: I can see if I route it somewhere else that's working, so my guess is that it's getting redirected to admin_projects_path then something must throw it back to admin_login_path and I am not quite sure what that is

Comment: Yeah, hard to say without more code. My answer was more to point you in the right direction of how to structure the controllers to fit your needs. You'll probably have to work out the kinks that are specific to your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call adminLogin from ProjectsController, it should be defined either in ApplicationController or in a common parent class which derives from ApplicationController.

Comment: So should I place that method under applicationController?